# Add button to each row returned from database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to add a button at the bottom of each row returned from the database, but cannot work out how i would do this. The button should be a simple 'submit' style button.

```
include("shared.php");

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 

    function __construct($it) { 

        //going through each field - lowest level
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
        return parent::key(). ": " . parent::current(). "</td>" . "<br/>";
    }

    //goes through, the first row returned
    function beginChildren() { 
        echo "  " . "<br/>"; 
    } 

    //last one
    function endChildren() { 
        echo "</tr>" . "<br/>";
    } 
} 

$database = new PDO("DATABASE CONNECTION");
$database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM Books"); 
$query->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$rows = $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($query->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
    echo $v;
}
```

Comment: I have fixed this now, it required a button at      function endChildren() { 
         echo "</tr>" . "<button type='submit' value='Submit'>Submit</button>". "<br/>";
     }

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it later. Dont put it in as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the button on to the end of your echo in the penultimate line:

```
echo $v . "<button>submit</button>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($query->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
    echo $v . '<button type="button">Submit</button>';
}
```

Comment: This transform's each attribute returned into a button. I wish for one button to be displayed per row returned from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
echo $v . "<button type='submit' value='Submit'>Submit</button>" in your foreach.
```

Comment: Strangly this adds a button to all lines. I want it to display a button just at the bottom of each Block.

Comment: "I want to add a button at the bottom of each row returned from the database" - this is what you asked for mate